# Intercepting/overriding Name property on custom control?

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-controls, controls

I have a custom version of a label control (built using a user control).  While working in the designer, I want to intercept the setting of the Name property (in the properties panel) and use it to generate the Text property.  That is, if I enter "lblFirstName" into the Name property of the properties panel I want to immediately see that the Text property is set to "First Name".

Parsing the Name property is not the issue; I can do that.

I have tried to overload/shadow the Name property (since "Overrides" is not allowed) to essentially add this "aspect" to our custom label control but it doesn't seem to hit the Shadowed method at design time.  It does hit the Shadowed method at run time if manipulated via code.

The point is to avoid double the work as the label text and the label name are essentially the same.  The only difference is one is formatted to be human friendly and the other machine friendly.

```
<System.ComponentModel.Browsable(True),
 System.ComponentModel.ParenthesizePropertyName(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
Public Shadows Property Name As String
    Get
        Return MyBase.Name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        MyBase.Name = value
        If Me.DesignMode Then
            Me.Text = Humanize(value)
        End If
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property
```

This may be a matter of picking the right attributes.  I'm not sure.

Conversely, if it's an easier alternative, we could allow setting the Text property to set the Name property.  I doubt this would be easier since it should also reflect the new name in the Designer.vb code, not just in the label's Name property itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with some extra design time elements.  The `IComponentChangeService` is your hook to design time change events.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class RenameLabel
     Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Label
     Private WithEvents _compChServ As IComponentChangeService

     Public Overrides Property Site() As ISite
         Get
            Return MyBase.Site
         End Get
         Set(ByVal Value As ISite)
            If _compChServ IsNot Nothing Then _
               RemoveHandler _compChServ.ComponentRename, AddressOf nameChanged

            MyBase.Site = Value

            _compChServ = CType(GetService(GetType(IComponentChangeService)), _
                          IComponentChangeService)

            If _compChServ IsNot Nothing Then _
               AddHandler _compChServ.ComponentRename, AddressOf nameChanged
         End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub nameChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As _
                            ComponentRenameEventArgs)
         'Add your change code here
         Me.Text = Me.Name
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If _compChServ IsNot Nothing Then _
               RemoveHandler _compChServ.ComponentRename, AddressOf nameChanged
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

End Class
```

[MSDN - IComponentChangeService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.icomponentchangeservice%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[MSDN - ISite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.site%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

**EDIT** :  added disposing code!